# generated .exe file is not running completely, getting no module found error and sometimes current directory is not working

Tags: python, excel, pycharm, pyinstaller

1.installed pyinstaller

2.created sample.py file inside this file kept kivy app code
while running this it should initialize the kivy app.

3. in Sample.py file I mentioned the workbook "test.xlsx"

path for sample.py "c:/drive/myprojects/sample.py"
path for test.xlsx "c:/drive/myprojects/test.xlsx"

4. in the test.xlsx, created my modules name sheets.
5. each sheet will have particular number test cases name and yes or No options

for ex: Col A contains a value Test1.py and Col B contains "Yes" or "No"

6. I wrote a code in sample.py such way that only if the test case name contains Yes then it should run via kivya app after selecting particular module.
7. while running this pyinstaller --onefile --noconfirm --clean sample.py
   it will create a dist folder inside that will have sample.exe file.
8. while running that **sample.exe** file it will initialize the kivy app and I will select the particular module.
9. after selecting the module it throwing **no module found error **
   and current directory is **c:/drive/myprojects/dist**

I tried by keeping setup.py

inside this file i created a setup for cz_freezer and py2exe and pyoxidizer
nothing has worked

I Tried by adding --add options then also its not working

but while running sample.py file in PyCharm I'm able to pass the script

while running in pyinstaller only I'm facing above mentioned problem

expecting: sample.exe file should generate and, while running sample.exe file kivy app should initialize and scripts should pass